# Can I import contacts from Outlook into CiviCRM?

Tags: contacts, import

Is it possible to transfer a contact list from Microsoft 365 Outlook to CiviCRM using a csv. File?

I don't understand this formating business, it's a simple enough question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good explanation about importing contacts in to civicrm using csv in this chapter of the book. It doesn't matter where those contacts' data originated.

https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/importing-data/

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the process of doing this too.  What I found though is that Outlook contacts are all individuals whereas Civi contacts can be either Organisations or Individuals, so unless there is a great level of consistency with naming conventions, they won't all necessarily match up.  (Ie, contacts from the same organisation won't necessarily match up)
I therefore created two excel spreadsheets, one with the individual contacts, and searched for similar terms to standardise the company names.  Then I created a new spreadsheet for the organisations, and have an intern populating it with central phone and email addresses (all my outlook one's were for individual people) it so I can upload it all consistently.
Not finished yet though!